# Angular ngx translate missing locale data for the locale

Tags: angular, date, ngx-translate

I have an angular application that uses ngx translate. So I mi up a pipe that format a date according to the language

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'localizedDate',
  pure: false
})
export class LocalizedDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
  }
    
  transform(value: any, pattern: string = 'shortDate'): any {
    const datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe(this.translateService.currentLang);
    return datePipe.transform(value, pattern);
  }
}
```

In local I am no problem but when I build with the production mode I encounter the following problem:

I get the following error:

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "fr". ' for pipe 't'

Example of a date I get from my api: `2021-06-10T12:12:29.787428+00:00`

Comment: What data are you passing as input to the pipe? What is the result? And what did you expect? Also what is you current language?

Comment: The aactuelle language is French. The value I transmit is the following: 2021-06-10T12:12:29.787428
I get the following error: Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "fr". ' for pipe 't'

Answer (score 2):

This is not ngx translate issue, you need register locale data with Angular before using date or currency pipe etc for formatting.

e.g. for french

```
    import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
    import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';

...............    
    registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr', localeFrExtra);
    registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR', localeFrExtra);
```